# Finding it difficult to update a listbox dynamically within a tikinter window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, listbox, python-3.4

I am creating a simple tkinter list and populating it with a list of numbers. then I am deleting a part of the list and want that change to reflect in the listbox as soon as I run the delete function.

I used the `update_idletasks()` in the function but it does not update the list. Can some one assist me to resolve this issue?

```
from tkinter import *


main = Tk()

b1 = Button(main,text='delete section',command=lambda:func())
b1.pack()

l1 = Listbox(main)
l1.pack()

mylist =[]

for i in range(0,100):
    mylist.append(i)

for k in mylist:
    l1.insert(0,k)

def func():
    del mylist[50:100]
l1.update_idletasks()

main.mainloop()
```

Comment: By the way I am using python 3.4

Answer (score 1):

> update_idletasks(self)
>
> Enter event loop until all idle callbacks have been called. This will update the display of windows but not process events caused by the user.

`update_idletasks` is not what you're wanting to use if you just want to update the Listbox with the new list.

There are a few ways you can do this. You can delete all items from index 50 to 100

```
l1.delete(50, 100)
```

Or you can delete every item from the list and add them again

```
del mylist[50:100]
li.delete(0, END)
for k in mylist:
    l1.insert(0, k)
```

Also, if you wish to use the first option, deleting from index 50 to 100. You'll need to change your current insert line from `l1.insert(0, k)` to `l1.insert(END, k)` this way it adds to the list in a ascending order.

I'm mentioning this because it appears you want to keep `0, 1, .. , 48, 49`. But if you want them in descending order then use `l1.delete(0, 49)` instead.

Comment: Thank you. I like the second option, essentially that means I am dropping the current updated list box and recreating it from the updated list. It works.